# Retrieving products revenue in Google Analytics via its API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

In Ecommerce section of Google Analytics I have products revenue in % and $. How can I retrieve those from API?

I don't need the exact code, I just need the way explaining how to retrieve them directly or calculate them.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I know how to retrieve all the information I need but products revenue. I have a functioning code in Ruby already.

Comment: a good place to start would be:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Comment: @DaImTo, look at my update

Comment: @DaImTo, where's the revenue per product in there?